# SIGABRT in drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crashlytics

Sorry, if this question is too fuzzy, but I really don't understand what's happening.
I have an app with integrated `crashlytics` lib.  And I have one strange crash in view with some plot. Here's log:
[image]
line 102 is

```
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(kLeftHorizontalMargin + xScale*i/2, kVerticalTopMargin + (maxValue - value)*yScale) radius:kPathLineWidth startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:YES];
```

and a bit more:

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

```
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3846f1fc __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x384d6a53 pthread_kill + 58
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x3842002d abort + 76
3  libsystem_c.dylib              0x383ffc6b __assert_rtn + 182
4  CoreGraphics                   0x2dc60563 CGPathAddArc + 186
5  UIKit                          0x30589ed7 -[UIBezierPath addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:] + 70
6  Exchange                       0x00010d25 -[GraphView drawRect:] (GraphView.m:102)
7  UIKit                          0x303cb749 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 372
8  QuartzCore                     0x30002049 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 100
9  QuartzCore                     0x2ffeb813 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 1858
10 QuartzCore                     0x300c5735 ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 52
11 QuartzCore                     0x2ffeb0c3 x_blame_allocations + 82
12 QuartzCore                     0x2ffead77 CA::Layer::display_() + 1118
13 QuartzCore                     0x2ffce969 CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 208
14 QuartzCore                     0x2ffce601 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 24
15 QuartzCore                     0x2ffce00d CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 228
16 QuartzCore                     0x2ffcde1f CA::Transaction::commit() + 314
17 QuartzCore                     0x2ffc7b4d CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 56
18 CoreFoundation                 0x2db90f71 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
19 CoreFoundation                 0x2db8e8ff __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 286
20 CoreFoundation                 0x2db8ec4b __CFRunLoopRun + 738
21 CoreFoundation                 0x2daf9541 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
22 CoreFoundation                 0x2daf9323 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
23 GraphicsServices               0x328302eb GSEventRunModal + 138
24 UIKit                          0x303b01e5 UIApplicationMain + 1136
25 Exchange                       0x00022507 main (main.m:16)
```

And here's my `drawRect:`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    if (self.datesAndValues.count == 0)
        return;

    double xScale = (self.frame.size.width - kLeftHorizontalMargin - kRightHorizontalMargin)/((self.datesAndValues.count - 1)/2);
    double yScale;
    if (maxValue == minValue)
        yScale = 1;
    else
        yScale = (self.frame.size.height - kVerticalTopMargin - kVerticalBottomMargin)/(maxValue - minValue);

    [self drawWeekSeparatorsInRect:rect
                        withXScale:xScale];

    UIFont* bigFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:kMinMaxLabelFontSize];
    UIFont* smallFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:kLocalMinMaxLabelFontSize];

    UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    for (NSInteger i=0; i<self.datesAndValues.count; i+=2)
    {
        double value = [self.datesAndValues[i+1] doubleValue];
        if (i == 0)
            [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(kLeftHorizontalMargin, kVerticalTopMargin + (maxValue - value)*yScale)];
        else
            [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(kLeftHorizontalMargin + xScale*i/2, kVerticalTopMargin + (maxValue - value)*yScale)];

        if (i == self.datesAndValues.count - 2)
            [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(kLeftHorizontalMargin + xScale*i/2, kVerticalTopMargin + (maxValue - value)*yScale) radius:kPathLineWidth startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:YES];

        NSDate* date = self.datesAndValues[i];
        if ([self.datesOfMax containsObject:date] &&
            value != maxValue)
        {
            UIColor* textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            NSDictionary* stringAttrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName : smallFont,
                                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor };
            NSString* maxValueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", value];
            NSAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:maxValueString
                                                                          attributes:stringAttrs];
            CGFloat x = kLeftHorizontalMargin + xScale*i/2;
            CGRect textRect = [maxValueString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                        attributes:stringAttrs
                                                           context:nil];
            if (x + textRect.size.width + kLeftHorizontalMargin > self.frame.size.width)
                x = self.frame.size.width - textRect.size.width - kLeftHorizontalMargin;
            [attrStr drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, (maxValue - value)*yScale)];
        }

        if (value == maxValue)
        {
            UIColor* textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            NSDictionary* stringAttrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName : bigFont,
                                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor };
            NSString* maxValueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", value];
            NSAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:maxValueString
                                                                          attributes:stringAttrs];
            CGRect textRect = [maxValueString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                        attributes:stringAttrs
                                                            context:nil];
            CGFloat x = kLeftHorizontalMargin + xScale*i/2 - textRect.size.width;
            if (x < kLeftHorizontalMargin)
                x = kLeftHorizontalMargin;
            [attrStr drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, kMaxValueVerticalTopMargin + (maxValue - value)*yScale)];
        }

        if ([self.datesOfMin containsObject:date] &&
            value != minValue)
        {
            UIColor* textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            NSDictionary* stringAttrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName : smallFont,
                                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor };
            NSString* minValueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", value];
            NSAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:minValueString
                                                                          attributes:stringAttrs];
            CGFloat x = kLeftHorizontalMargin + xScale*i/2;

            [attrStr drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, kVerticalTopMargin + (maxValue - value)*yScale)];
        }
        if (value == minValue)
        {
            UIColor* textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            NSDictionary* stringAttrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName : bigFont,
                                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor };
            NSString* minValueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", value];
            NSAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:minValueString
                                                                          attributes:stringAttrs];
            CGFloat x = kLeftHorizontalMargin + xScale*i/2;
            CGRect textRect = [minValueString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                        attributes:stringAttrs
                                                           context:nil];
            if (x + textRect.size.width + kLeftHorizontalMargin > self.frame.size.width)
                x = self.frame.size.width - textRect.size.width - kLeftHorizontalMargin;
            [attrStr drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, kVerticalTopMargin + (maxValue - value)*yScale)];
        }
    }
    path.lineWidth = kPathLineWidth;
    [[UIColor lightGrayColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}
```

Comment: Any exception text generated?

Comment: What log are you interesting in? I think, the problem is in `addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:`

Comment: The logs you provide are fine, but often there are exception messages generated if you continue execution after catching the exception.  This might not apply to you, but this message is often more useful than the stacktrace.

Comment: @trojanfoe, I couldn't produce this crash in debug. I have only crashlytics report

Comment: OK.  Indicate which line is 102.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code crashes if you have only one date/value pair in `self.datesAndValues`.
Look at this line:

```
double xScale = (self.frame.size.width - kLeftHorizontalMargin - kRightHorizontalMargin)/((self.datesAndValues.count - 1)/2);
```

If `self.datesAndValues` has a count of 2, the resulting value for xScale is `+Inf` because `((self.datesAndValues.count - 1)/2)` will be 0.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'll try to simulate this case add accept answer